# Converting Pixels to Bezier Curves in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4, trace, bezier, pixel

Ok, so I'll try to be as descriptive as possible.

I'm working on a project for a client that requires a jibjab-style masking feature of an uploaded image.

I would like to be able to generate a database-storable object that contains anchor/control positions of a bezier shape, so I can pull it out later and re-mask the object. This all is pretty easy to do, except for one catch : I need to create the bezier object from a user-drawn outline.

So far, here's how I imagine the process going:

on mouse down, create a new sprite, beginFill, and moveTo mouse position.

on mouse move, lineTo an XY coordinate.

on mouse up, endFill.

This all works just great. I could just store the info here, but I would be looking at a GIGANTIC object full of tons of pretty useless x/y coordinates, and no way to really make fine-tuning changes outside of putting handles on every pixel. (I may as well give the end user a pencil tool...)

Here's what I'm thinking as far as bezier curve calculation goes :

1: Figure out when I need to start a new curve, and track the xy of the pixel on this interval. I'm imagining this being just a pixel count, maybe just increment a count variable per mouse move and make a new one every x pixels. The issue here is some curves would be inaccurate, and others unnecessary, but I really just need a general area, not an exact representation, so it could work. I'd be happier with something a little smarter though.

2: take each new x/y, store it as an anchor, and figure out where a control would go to make the line curve between this and the last anchor. this is where I get really hung up. I'm sure someone has done this in flash, but no amount of googling can seem to help me out with the way to get this done. I've done a lot of sketching and what little math I can wrap my brain around, but can't seem to figure out a way of converting pixels to beziers.

Is this possible? All I really need is something that will get close to the same shape. I'm thinking about maybe only placing anchors when the angle of the next pixel is beyond 180 degrees in relation to the current line or something, and just grabbing the edge of the arc between these changes, but no matter how hard I try, I can't seem to figure out how to get this working!

Thanks for your help, I'll be sure to post my progress here as I go, I think this could be really useful in many applications, as long as it's actually feasible...

Jesse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers, although I guess I probably should be more specific about the application, I'm really only needing an outline for a mask, so converting images to vectors or polygons, despite how cool that is, doesn't really fix my issue. The linear least squares algorithm is mega cool, I think this might be closer to what I'm looking for.

I have a basic workaround going right now, I'm just counting mouse moves, then every X (playing with it to get most desirable curve) moves, I grab the xy position. then, I take every other stored xy, and turn it into an anchor, the remaining xys are turned into controls. This is producing somewhat desirable results, but has some minor issues, in that the speed at which the mask is drawn effects the number of handles, and it's really just getting a general area, not a precise fit.
Interestingly, users seem to draw slower for more precise shapes, so this solution works a lot better than I had imagined, but it's not as nice as it could be. This will work for the client, so although there's no reason to pursue it further, I like learning new things, and will spend some off the clock time looking into linear least equations and seeing if I can drum up a class that will do these computations for me. If anyone runs across some AS3 code for this type of thing, or would like some of mine, let me know, this is an interesting puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a lot of work to turn pixels into Bezier curves. You could try using something like the Linear least squares algorithm. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares

A different tact, could you have your users draw vector graphics instead? That way you can just store the shapes in the database.

Another cool method of converting raster to vector would be something like this iterative program: http://rogeralsing.com/2008/12/07/genetic-programming-evolution-of-mona-lisa/

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

In my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891643/twitter-image-encoding-challenge) I discuss using [autotrace](http://autotrace.sourceforge.net/) to convert bitmaps to beziers. I recommend passing your user drawing through this program on the server. Autotrace does a fantastic job of tracing and simplifying so there is no need to try and reinvent the wheel here.