# Fractal based Image compression algorithm (and source code)

Tags: math, encoding, image, compression, fractals

I am looking for a decent fractal based compression algorithm for images. So far I only find dead links to the FIF image format and dead links pointing to Iterated Systems Inc which then became MediaBin which then became nothing from what I can see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source files in ANSI C (enc.c and dec.c) for PIFS (i.e. partition iterated function system) are available on the website of [Fractal Image Compression: Theory and Application to Digital Images](http://inls.ucsd.edu/~fisher/Fractals/) book.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should take a look at the [Fiasco library](https://github.com/megatherion/Fiasco). You can find an old [article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/4367) about it on Linux Journal.

Answer (score 1):

The "nanocrunch.cpp" source code, implementing, yet another variant on fractal image compression, was developed by "Boojum", and is the top answer to another Stack Overflow question: [Twitter image encoding challenge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891643/twitter-image-encoding-challenge) .