# Code Golf - Banner Generation

Tags: language-agnostic, code-golf, rosetta-stone

When thanking someone, you don't want to just send them an e-mail saying "Thanks!", you want to have something FLASHY:

```
Input: THANKS!!
Output:
TTT H H AAA N N K K SSS !!! !!! 
 T  H H A A NNN K K S   !!! !!! 
 T  HHH AAA NNN KK  SSS !!! !!! 
 T  H H A A N N K K   S            
 T  H H A A N N K K SSS !!! !!!
```

Write a program to generate a banner. You only have to generate upper-case A-Z along with spaces and exclamation points (what is a banner without an exclamation point?). All characters are made up of a 3x5 grid of the same character (so the S is a 3x5 grid made of S). All output should be on one row (so no newlines). Here are all the letters you need:

```
Input: ABCDEFGHIJKL
Output:
AAA BBB CCC DD  EEE FFF GGG H H III JJJ K K L
A A B B C   D D E   F   G   H H  I    J K K L
AAA BBB C   D D EE  FF  G G HHH  I    J KK  L
A A B B C   D D E   F   G G H H  I  J J K K L
A A BBB CCC DD  EEE F   GGG H H III JJJ K K LLL

Input: MNOPQRSTUVWX
Output:
M M N N OOO PPP QQQ RR  SSS TTT U U V V W W X X
MMM NNN O O P P Q Q R R S    T  U U V V W W  X
M M NNN O O PPP Q Q RR  SSS  T  U U V V WWW  X
M M N N O O P   QQQ R R   S  T  U U V V WWW  X
M M N N OOO P   QQQ R R SSS  T  UUU  V  WWW X X

Input: YZ!
Output:
Y Y ZZZ !!!
Y Y   Z !!!
YYY  Z  !!!
  Y Z
YYY ZZZ !!!
```

The winner is the **shortest source code**, as counted by the number of bytes it takes to store the file in **utf-8 encoding**. Source code should read input from stdin, output to stdout. You can assume input will only contain `[A-Z! ]`. If you insult the user on incorrect input, you get a 10 character discount =P.

I was going to require these exact 28 characters, but to make it more interesting, you can choose how you want them to look - whatever makes your code shorter! To prove that your letters do look like normal letters, show the output of the last three runs.

---

Shortest codes so far, in characters (utf8 encoding if non-ASCII present):

### 133 J

### 205 Python

### 209 Ruby

### 313 Haskell

### 345 C89

### 382 F#

Comment: I don't understand: "All output should be on one row".  How is that possible given 5 text line character height?

Comment: @doublep: is suppose this means there are no multi-line banners.

Comment: Should spaces be supported or not?

Comment: You have to support spaces. And yep, I meant one row of 5-character tall letters

Comment: Can we ban `figlet` and count the code size by UTF-8?

Comment: @KennyTM: good idea.. would make it more fair.

Comment: The best way to do this is Figlet :-)

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 43, accepted):

### J, 133 <s>135</s> <s>79</s> <s>83</s> <s>84</s> <s>88</s> characters (utf-8 encoding)

```
;/5 3$"1(' ',.s){~"1#:3 u:(ucp'翇篭篯礧歮禧禤祯寭璗牯宭䤧彭忭筯篤筿殭秏璒孯孪寿咕寏犧'){~0>.64-~a.i.s=:
```

Usage:

```
    ;/5 3$"1(' ',.s){~"1#:3 u:(ucp'翇篭篯礧歮禧禤祯寭璗牯宭䤧彭忭筯篤筿殭秏璒孯孪寿咕寏犧'){~0>.64-~a.i.s=:'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ !'
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
│AAA│BBB│CCC│DD │EEE│FFF│GGG│H H│III│JJJ│K K│L  │M M│N N│OOO│PPP│QQQ│RR │SSS│TTT│U U│V V│W W│X X│Y Y│ZZZ│   │!!!│
│A A│B B│C  │D D│E  │F  │G  │H H│ I │  J│K K│L  │MMM│NNN│O O│P P│Q Q│R R│S  │ T │U U│V V│W W│ X │Y Y│  Z│   │!!!│
│AAA│BBB│C  │D D│EE │FF │G G│HHH│ I │  J│KK │L  │M M│NNN│O O│PPP│Q Q│RR │SSS│ T │U U│V V│WWW│ X │YYY│ Z │   │!!!│
│A A│B B│C  │D D│E  │F  │G G│H H│ I │J J│K K│L  │M M│N N│O O│P  │QQQ│R R│  S│ T │U U│V V│WWW│ X │  Y│Z  │   │   │
│A A│BBB│CCC│DD │EEE│F  │GGG│H H│III│JJJ│K K│LLL│M M│N N│OOO│P  │QQQ│R R│SSS│ T │UUU│ V │WWW│X X│YYY│ZZZ│   │!!!│
└───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘

    ;/5 3$"1(' ',.s){~"1#:3 u:(ucp'翇篭篯礧歮禧禤祯寭璗牯宭䤧彭忭筯篤筿殭秏璒孯孪寿咕寏犧'){~0>.64-~a.i.s=:'this is incorrect input.'
|index error
```

Explanation (`NB.` is comment in J):

```
;/              NB. String together along the third dimension...
5 3$"1          NB. ... reshape each line to 5x3...
(' ',.s)        NB. ... a space before each letter of the input string...
{~"1            NB. ... indexed using...
#:              NB. ... the (15 bit) binary representation of ...
3 u:            NB. ... the integer representation of...
(ucp'翇篭篯礧歮禧禤祯寭璗牯宭䤧彭忭筯篤筿殭秏璒孯孪寿咕寏犧')  ... the unicode versions of these code points...
{~              NB. ...indexed using...
0>.             NB. ...the max of 0 and...
64-~            NB. ...64 less than...
a.i.            NB. the ascii indexes of s
s=:             NB. Assign the input string to the variable s.
```

Comment: @M28: Awesome is what this is.

Comment: @M28: Explanation added. Basically each of the 28 unicode characters is a 15-bit integer which is a binary representation of the letter. For example, the first one represents 'A', and is equivalent to 111101111101101 (or 31725)

Comment: This hurts my head, eyes, cheeks, tongue and my heart. But I love it.

Comment: How dare you insult my mother like that!? Otherwise, awesome! ;o)

Comment: @deceze: I was kinda wondering if that actually means anything in Chinese! :)

Comment: Although I don't really speak Chinese ("only" Japanese) I don't think it does as a whole. Maybe some word fragments here or there. :)

Comment: i wonder if this is an abuse of code golf, though. a "char" is typically thought of as 8 bytes, while those codepoints are 16 bytes right?

Comment: also haha how pretentious/funny is it that a comment in J is a latin abbreviation? (NB meaning "note bene" meaning "take note")

Comment: My antivirs complained about the 篭篯礧歮禧禤祯寭璗牯宭䤧 part

Comment: Hmmm, ok this is cheating - at least with respect to counting the code size. How much does the text take when saved on disk?
You'll have to save it either in UCS-2 in 158bytes or __UTF-8 in ~135 bytes__. I think utf8 is a good choice to standardize in counting, and in it each of the chinese characters will be 3 bytes.

Comment: i've updated the char count to reflect the cost, in bytes, with UTF-8 (as produced by saving the file with notepad in UTF-8 encoding)

Comment: Congratulations, your program (probably) fits in a tweet.

Comment: @Brian If we'd count "Twitter characters" this would still be 79 chars. :)

Comment: @deceze: This is where you say, "but I'm not bitter." Yeah, seeing random Unicode just reminds me of the Twitter Image Encoding Challenge ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/891643/twitter-image-encoding-challenge )

Comment: @EnTerr: Are you sure the count is correct? I get 132 bytes in UTF-8. 133 if I add a '\n'

Comment: @EnTerr & myself: Because Notepad is a braindead text-editor. It's 132 bytes in UTF-8. You only arrive at 135, I *think* if you add in a BOM, which 1) is sad and unneeded with UTF-8 and 2) Will probably screw with the compiler/interpreter/whatever reads J (I don't speak J myself.)

Comment: @Thanatos: note i said ~(approx) 135 :). i have no clue what encoding representation does J compiler "eat". 

The reason Byte-Order-Mark may be used at start of a Unicode file is to distinguish if it is UTF-16 in little-endian byte order (0xFF 0xFE) or UTF-16 in big-endian (0xFE 0xFF) or UTF-8 (0xEF 0xBB 0xBF).
<http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#bom5>

Answer (score 16):

## Python, <strike>250</strike> 224 chars

```
s=raw_input()
for i in range(5):
    for c in s:
        print''.join((' ',c)[int('2zj93fqzj6hsh2bc8i2b1ycncj5yc2v9i0m16dz91gcizj18blbw6wt0p3qqh8svchwc5onna2808of',36)>>((ord(c)-65 if c>'@'else 26)*15+i*3+j)&1]for j in[0,1,2]),
    print
```

Notes:

- relies on 2.x print statement considerably;
- supports spaces.

Running (I changed appearance of a few letters, for aestetic reasons only ;):

```
$ echo ABCDEFGHIJKL | python code-golf.py
AAA BBB CCC DD  EEE FFF GGG H H III JJJ K K L   
A A B B C   D D E   F   G   H H  I    J K K L   
AAA BBB C   D D EEE FFF G   HHH  I    J KK  L   
A A B B C   D D E   F   G G H H  I  J J K K L   
A A BBB CCC DD  EEE F   GGG H H III JJJ K K LLL 

$ echo MNOPQRSTUVWX | python code-golf.py
M M N N OOO PPP QQQ RR  SSS TTT U U V V W W X X 
MMM NNN O O P P Q Q R R S    T  U U V V W W X X 
M M NNN O O PPP Q Q RR  SSS  T  U U V V WWW  X  
M M N N O O P   QQQ R R   S  T  U U V V WWW X X 
M M N N OOO P   QQQ R R SSS  T  UUU  V  W W X X 

$ echo YZ\! | python code-golf.py
Y Y ZZZ !!! 
Y Y   Z !!! 
YYY  Z  !!! 
  Y Z       
YYY ZZZ !!!
```

There are trailing spaces.

Comment: Hmm, 2 revisions?  Looks like SO combined several short-succession edits into one.

Comment: @Brian: Yes, starting with revision 4.

Answer (score 9):

## **Figlet (0 chars)**

```
wget -q 3.ly/gzkv;figlet -f b
```

Sample output:

```
% wget -q 3.ly/gzkv;figlet -f b ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS

 A  BB   CC DD  EEE FFF  GG H H III  JJ K K L   M M NNN  O  PP   Q  RR   SS 
A A B B C   D D E   F   G   H H  I    J K K L   MMM N N O O P P Q Q R R S   
AAA BB  C   D D EE  FF  G G HHH  I    J KK  L   MMM N N O O PP  Q Q RR   S  
A A B B C   D D E   F   G G H H  I  J J K K L   M M N N O O P    QQ R R   S 
A A BB   CC DD  EEE F    GG H H III  J  K K LLL M M N N  O  P     Q R R SS 
% wget -q 3.ly/gzkv;figlet -f b TUVWXYZ \!

TTT U U V V W W X X Y Y ZZZ     !!! 
 T  U U V V W W X X Y Y   Z     !!! 
 T  U U V V WWW  X   Y   Z      !!! 
 T  U U V V WWW X X  Y  Z           
 T  UUU  V  W W X X  Y  ZZZ     !!!
```

Comment: definitely beats the perl one! doesnt count but i'm upvoting anyway

Comment: when trying "wget -q 3.ly/gzkv;figlet -f b", i get **-bash: figlet: command not found**. Is "figlet" part of bash? I didn't think so...
Change the name of the "language" from Bash to **Figlet**!

Comment: This is about as appropriate solution to the problem, as claiming that "wget -q --output-document=- 3.ly/DhWP" solves the problem "calculate and print the first 10000 digits of Pi" ;-)

Comment: Downvoting.  This is a nice solution, but the source is about four kilobytes!  That's not how you make a golf solution.

Answer (score 7):

### Python, <strike>233</strike> <strike>231</strike> <strike>225</strike> <strike>224</strike> 205 chars

Candidate for the shortest python solution here :-)
It is a two-liner - last line was broken in 3 for urrrr *readability*

```
s=raw_input()
for i in range(5):print' '.join(''.join((' ',c)[ord(
'W_E__U__QQ_QN_UQ_EA_Q]_D_Q_QYQ__D[_PP_B__F__Q__EG_Y__EZWU]A_A_P_OPO_\\_QNQWT_YUS'
[max(0,3*ord(c)-192-k)])>>i&1]for k in(2,1,0))for c in s)
```

ps. Thanks for comments, corrected issues and now using 7-bit ASCII only!

Test banner:

```
TTT H H EEE     QQQ U U III CCC K K     BBB RR  OOO W W N N     FFF OOO X X     JJJ U U M M PPP SSS     OOO V V EEE RR      TTT H H EEE     L   AAA ZZZ Y Y     DD  OOO GGG !!!
 T  H H E       Q Q U U  I  C   K K     B B R R O O W W NNN     F   O O  X        J U U MMM P P S       O O V V E   R R      T  H H E       L   A A   Z Y Y     D D O O G   !!!
 T  HHH EE      Q Q U U  I  C   KK      BBB RR  O O WWW NNN     FF  O O  X        J U U M M PPP SSS     O O V V EE  RR       T  HHH EE      L   AAA  Z  YYY     D D O O G G !!!
 T  H H E       QQQ U U  I  C   K K     B B R R O O WWW N N     F   O O  X      J J U U M M P     S     O O V V E   R R      T  H H E       L   A A Z     Y     D D O O G G    
 T  H H EEE     QQQ UUU III CCC K K     BBB R R OOO WWW N N     F   OOO X X     JJJ UUU M M P   SSS     OOO  V  EEE R R      T  H H EEE     LLL A A ZZZ YYY     DD  OOO GGG !!!
```

Comment: Could you specify the version used? Does not work in my Python 2.6.2 installation (saved as utf-8). PS: `ÃÂÁ` does not qualify as ASCII ;-)

Comment: @ChristopheD: that's true.. for this program to work everywhere you'd have to specify an encoding, and that would take up a comment line at the top of your file.

Comment: `IndexError: string index out of range` for Python 2.6.1

Comment: @wallacoloo: I checked it works on 2.5.2 and 2.6.5, no reason to believe it won't on other version. Did you provide string with lower-case letters or digits? ;-) Only 'A..Z !' are allowed.
Consider yourself insulted: `If you insult the user on incorrect input, you get a 10 character discount`

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell, 313 <s>316</s> <s>320</s>

```
import Data.Bits
import Data.Char
c&True=c
c&_=' '
a ' '='@'
a '!'='['
a c=c
q s=unlines[s>>= \c->take 3(drop(84*n+3*(ord(a c)-64))$map((c&).testBit(0xffdebaf79f6fbfde7bfe8062f6a979b69b55a4d368ebaf6aeefbe9717add3f8f2ab6a36dbf9b1524d368fedb6fefff69bfdffbff8::Integer))[0..])++" "|n<-[0..4]]
main=getLine>>=putStr.q
```

For the curious, the large number is the hex version of `encoding` in the following code. The number is simply used as a bitmap. I've had no success with further shortening the code by encoding the number to other bases even with non-standard character representations.

```
formats :: [String] -- order: [ A-Z!] <- that's a space in front of A
formats = [
    "   AAABBBCCCDD EEEFFFGGGH HIIIJJJK KL  M MN NOOOPPPQQQRR SSSTTTU UV VW WX XY YZZZ!!!"
  , "   A AB BC  D DE  F  G  H H I   JK KL  MMMNNNO OP PQ QR RS   T U UV VW W X Y Y  Z!!!"
  , "   AAABBBC  D DEE FF G GHHH I   JKK L  M MNNNO OPPPQ QRR SSS T U UV VWWW X YYY Z !!!"
  , "   A AB BC  D DE  F  G GH H I J JK KL  M MN NO OP  QQQR R  S T U UV VWWW X   YZ     "
  , "   A ABBBCCCDD EEEF  GGGH HIIIJJJK KLLLM MN NOOOP  QQQR RSSS T UUU V WWWX XYYYZZZ!!!"
  ]

charToBool :: Char -> Bool
charToBool ' ' = False
charToBool _   = True

boolToInteger :: Bool -> Integer
boolToInteger True = 1
boolToInteger _    = 0

encoding :: Integer
encoding = foldr f 0 $ zip [0..] $ map charToBool $ concat formats
  where
    f (pow, bool) z = z + ((2^pow) * boolToInteger bool)
```

Answer (score 3):

### Python 2.6, <strike>251</strike> - <strike>243</strike> - 227 characters

I tried a slightly different approach (bitpacking the *parts* the letters are made of) ...

- handles uppercase letters, spaces, exclamation mark.
- 2 unnecessary linebreaks added here for readability (the for loop could be one line)
- be sure to save this as UTF-8 with BOM!

As always, all comments and suggestions welcome! Contender for shortest Python solution (again a few characters behind at the moment)...

```
w=raw_input()
for l in range(5):print''.join("1111 11  11  1   1   "
[int(("%05d"%ord(u"<ϳϲࢬ禉ऐऒ࠾⬃ᅘᖆⰯ囌❿✛іϾь穏ࠂᅜ⭦⭪⫸㡩⬪㰼"
[max(0,ord(c)-64)]))[l])*3:][:3].replace("1",c)+" "for c in w)
```

Comment: ah, this `max(-1, .. )` for handling '!' is so clever - borrowed it for my code!

Comment: `Unsupported characters in input` :-(

Comment: @wallacoloo: as in the text, make sure that your editor saves this as utf-8 with BOM header (`0xEF,0xBB,0xBF`) as to indicate the utf-8 encoding; some editors may not support or strip this... As an alternative (more lengthy though) you could add `#coding:utf-8` at the top of the file.

Answer (score 2):

## C89, 345 characters

Newlines added for your sanity (they are not included in the character count and can/should be deleted):

```
char o[5][99];
d[]={0x2df7fbef,0x3927bb6b,0x396792cf,0x3da7dbed,0x3a4bfb27,0x2d76f249,0x2dbedbfd,0x3db793ef,0x3fb7daeb,0x3ce7a497,0x3db6ab6d,0x3ff6d495,0x3cf6f2a7,0x38ff8000};
c,i,j;
main(){memset(o,32,495);
while((c=getchar())>0){
for(j=0;j<15;j++)
o[j/3][i+j%3]=d[c-33?(c-65)/2:13]>>((c&1)*15+j)&1?c:32;i+=4;}
for(j=0;j<5;j++)printf("%.*s\n",i,o[j]);}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Ruby** : 207 <s>215 252 345</s> characters

```
i=gets.chomp;5.times{|t|p i.gsub(/./){|c|j=3*(c>?@?c.ord-64:0);(3*t..3*t+2).map{|d|"mini5mbmzjf2bqjmof3prl72i5pn138iuhylmkpi65i278kq3qjfaihyjb66787odp8ktiy5hwt78tmnb"[j..j+2].to_i(36)[d]==1?c:" "}.join+" "}}
```

Answer (score 1):

## F#, 382 chars

I compressed two letters from each row into an ascii-printable byte, and handled space and exclamation point specially.

```
let s,(!)=stdin.ReadLine(),printf"%s"
for n in 0..4 do
 for c in s do if c=' '||n=3&&c='!'then !"    "elif c='!'then !"!!! "else for x in 0..3 do printf"%c"(if(Array.collect(fun b->let B n=int b&&&n=0 in[|(B 64)||not(B 8);B 32;B 16;true;B 4;B 2;B 1;true|])"wvwuwTUwvwUUWUEDEiTwUUBURQwEfWidWWVrUrrUEDUmTUTuZUr\\WvtuwWUturruw"B).[n*104+(int c-int 'A')*4+x]then ' 'else c)
 !"\n"
```

Sample I/O below:

```
HELLO WORLD!!!
H H EEE L   L   OOO     W W OOO RR  L   DD  !!! !!! !!!
H H E   L   L   O O     W W O O R R L   D D !!! !!! !!!
HHH EE  L   L   O O     WWW O O RR  L   D D !!! !!! !!!
H H E   L   L   O O     WWW O O R R L   D D
H H EEE LLL LLL OOO     WWW OOO R R LLL DD  !!! !!! !!!

ABCDEFGHIJKL
AAA BBB CCC DD  EEE FFF GGG H H III JJJ K K L
A A B B C   D D E   F   G   H H  I    J K K L
AAA BBB C   D D EE  FF  G G HHH  I    J KK  L
A A B B C   D D E   F   G G H H  I  J J K K L
A A BBB CCC DD  EEE F   GGG H H III JJJ K K LLL

MNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
M M N N OOO PPP QQQ RR  SSS TTT U U V V W W X X Y Y ZZZ
MMM NNN O O P P Q Q R R S    T  U U V V W W  X  Y Y   Z
M M NNN O O PPP Q Q RR  SSS  T  U U V V WWW  X  YYY  Z
M M N N O O P   QQQ R R   S  T  U U V V WWW  X    Y Z
M M N N OOO P   QQQ R R SSS  T  UUU  V  WWW X X YYY ZZZ
```

Comment: You can replace `for something in start..end` with `for something=start to end`. You can also skip the indentations on the last two lines. I don't know how to shorthen it further without getting an aneurysm.

Answer (score 1):

### Python, 340 characters

```
d=dict((i,[23535,31727,29263,15211,29391,4815,31567,23533,29847,31527,23277,29257,23421,23549,31599,5103,32623,23275,31183,9367,31597,11117,32749,21653,31213,29351][i-65])for i in range(65,91))
d[33]=29183
d[32]=0
s=raw_input()
for l in range(5):
 p=""
 for c in s:
  for n in range(3):
   if d[ord(c)]&2**(3*l+n):p+=c
   else:p+=" "
  p+=" "
 print p
```

### sample output

```
>>> 
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ !
aaa bbb ccc dd  eee fff ggg h h iii jjj k k l   m m n n ooo ppp qqq rr  sss ttt u u v v w w x x y y zzz     !!! 
a a b b c   d d e   f   g   h h  i    j k k l   mmm nnn o o p p q q r r s    t  u u v v w w  x  y y   z     !!! 
aaa bbb c   d d ee  ff  g g hhh  i    j kk  l   m m nnn o o ppp q q rr  sss  t  u u v v www  x  yyy  z      !!! 
a a b b c   d d e   f   g g h h  i  j j k k l   m m n n o o p   qqq r r   s  t  u u v v www  x    y z           
a a bbb ccc dd  eee f   ggg h h iii jjj k k lll m m n n ooo p   qqq r r sss  t  uuu  v  www x x yyy zzz     !!! 
>>>
```

not too great, but it was fun writing it

**edit** whoops, I made the input be lowercase. fixed now, saved me one character too :)

Comment: The inner `if...else` could be replaced by a single liner: `p+=(" ",c)[d[ord(c)]&2**(3*l+n)>0]`

Comment: `d[32:34]=0,29183` can replace `d[33]=29183;d[32]=0` (saves 3 chars)

Comment: @wallacoloo
d is a dictionary, so I'm pretty sure that doesn't work(IDLE doesn't agree with it, anyway)

Comment: @bwamat, yep. I thought it was a list :<

Answer (score 1):

## Delphi, 397 chars

Ok, with all the begin/end statements Delphi probably will never be shorter than any other languages, but I do see a challenge in getting it as short as possible.

```
vvar s:String;i,j,k:Word;const F:Array[65..92]of Word=($5BEA,$3AEB,$624E,$3B6B,$72CF,$12CF,$6B4E,$5BED,$7497,$2B26,$5AED,$7249,$5BFD,$5B6F,$2B6A,$12EB,$4D6A,$5AEB,$388E,$2497,$7B6D,$2B6D,$5FED,$5AAD,$24AD,$72A7,$2092,$0000);begin S:=ParamStr(1);for j:=0 to 4 do begin for k:=1 to Length(S)do begin for i := 0 to 2 do Write((' '+S[k])[1+(F[ord(S[k])]shr(i+j*3))and 1]);Write(' ');end;WriteLn;end;end.
```

The font is built up like this:

```
010 110 011 110 111 111 011 101 111 011 101 100 101 111 010 110 010 110 011 111 101 101 101 101 101 111 010 000
101 101 100 101 100 100 100 101 010 001 101 100 111 101 101 101 101 101 100 010 101 101 101 101 101 001 010 000
111 110 100 101 110 110 101 111 010 001 110 100 111 101 101 110 101 110 010 010 101 101 111 010 010 010 010 000
101 101 100 101 100 100 101 101 010 101 101 100 101 101 101 100 011 101 001 010 101 101 111 101 010 100 000 000
101 110 011 110 111 100 011 101 111 010 101 111 101 101 010 100 001 101 110 010 111 010 101 101 010 111 010 000
```

The characters in this 5x3 font take up 15 bits and are stored in word (UINT16) in this order:

```
00 01 02
03 04 05
06 07 08
09 10 11
12 13 14
```

Formatted code:

```
var
  s:String;    
  i, j, k: Word;

const
  F: Array [65 .. 92] of Word = (
    $5BEA,$3AEB,$624E,$3B6B,    $72CF,$12CF,$6B4E,$5BED,
    $7497,$2B26,$5AED,$7249,    $5BFD,$5B6F,$2B6A,$12EB,
    $4D6A,$5AEB,$388E,$2497,    $7B6D,$2B6D,$5FED,$5AAD,
    $24AD,$72A7,$2092,$0000);

begin
  S := ParamStr(1);
  for j := 0 to 4 do
  begin
    for k := 1 to Length(S) do
    begin
      for i := 0 to 2 do
        Write((' '+S[k])[1+(F[ord(S[k])]shr(i+j*3))and 1]);
      Write(' ');
    end;
    WriteLn;
  end;
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python: 259 chars

Not the shortest, but considering it was my first Python script, I'm more than satisfied.

```
k=raw_input()
for i in range(5):print' '.join(''.join((' ',x)[int(z)]for z in bin(int(''.join('%02d'%(ord(q)-43)for q in'xwxvxabxwxbbdqbXWX@axbbUb_^qxXwd@kddcsbssqbXWvDabav7bs9+dwuvxdbuvssvxq')[i*28+'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ! '.find(x)],8))[2:])for x in k)
```

Answer (score 0):

## **Perl, 69 <strike>74</strike> <strike>77</strike> <strike>78</strike> <strike>79</strike> chars**

```
$a=<>;s:(?{$z=substr$a,$-[0]/4,1})z|#:$z:g,print for`figlet -f3x5 $a`
```

Sample output:

```
% echo ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS | perl banner.pl

 A  BB   CC DD  EEE FFF  GG H H III  JJ K K L   M M NNN  O  PP   Q  RR   SS 
A A B B C   D D E   F   G   H H  I    J K K L   MMM N N O O P P Q Q R R S   
AAA BB  C   D D EE  FF  G G HHH  I    J KK  L   MMM N N O O PP  Q Q RR   S  
A A B B C   D D E   F   G G H H  I  J J K K L   M M N N O O P    QQ R R   S 
A A BB   CC DD  EEE F    GG H H III  J  K K LLL M M N N  O  P     Q R R SS  
% echo TUVWXYZ \! | perl banner.pl 

TTT U U V V W W X X Y Y ZZZ      !  
 T  U U V V W W X X Y Y   Z      !  
 T  U U V V WWW  X   Y   Z       !  
 T  U U V V WWW X X  Y  Z           
 T  UUU  V  W W X X  Y  ZZZ      !
```

I assume you have figlet and [this figlet font](http://www.jave.de/figlet/fonts/details/3x5.html) installed on your system. :)

Comment: hah nice. what's amusing is the J implementation is only 1 character longer and doesn't rely on an external program =P. this doesn't count, though

Comment: Nowhere in the rules does it say you can't have dependencies on external programs! :)

Comment: No, but it's a safe assumption. Otherwise you can just make an external program that does it and have your program do nothing but pass it the input string. ;)

Comment: But figlet and the linked figlet font are both commonly installed on Linux systems, just like Perl!

Comment: Jordan, I have to agree. I was going to upvote, but no-go on the figlet!

Comment: @Jordan Lewis - since the main job is done by *figlet* and not by *Perl*, you should title your solution **Figlet**!
 ... Is that a programming language? ;-)

Comment: @Jordan: common code golf rules say that if you have external dependencies, you need to include those libraries in your code counts.  Therefore, the real character count would include all the figlet source code. :)

Answer (score 0):

## C#, <strike>239 231</strike> 229 chars (292 bytes)

I'm a bit late but this just looked like fun.

```
using C=System.Console;class P{static void Main(){var t=C.ReadLine();for(int
b=15,s;b>0;b-=3){foreach(var c in t)for(s=0;s++<4;)C.Write(s>3||c<33?' ':((
"翇篭篯礧歮禧禤祯寭璗牯宭䤧彭忭筯篤筿殭秏璒孯孪寿咕寏犧"[c<34?0:c-64])&1<<b-s)>0
?c:' ');C.WriteLine();}}}
```