# Code Golf: ASCII Art number

Tags: digits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Code Golf - Banner Generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985540/code-golf-banner-generation)

Post your shortest code to convert a number into a ASCII art digits.

**Input** - Assume that an integer variable called **z** has already been set containing the number.

**Output** - Print the output to the console.

**Quality** - The lower number of characters, the better.

**Formatting** - Flexible, providing it is ASCII art and looks like a number. There must also be some spacing between digits.

**Test input: 365**

```
GGGGGGGGGGG....GGGGGGGGGGGG...GGGGGGGGGGG
..........G....G..............G..........
..........G....G..............G..........
..GGGGGGGGG....GGGGGGGGGGGG...GGGGGGGGGGG
..........G....G..........G.............G
..........G....G..........G.............G
GGGGGGGGGGG....GGGGGGGGGGGG...GGGGGGGGGGG
```

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24242/acceptable-level-of-code-golf-questions. Not a bad code golf, just needs a little more specification.

Comment: You should probably also add how each number is represented in this `7x11` matrix. Also things like spacing between each character - should there be 3 spaces between each printed digit? Are those dots only to indicate space, or must be part of the output?

Comment: Very similar to a [recent code-golf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985540/code-golf-banner-generation).

Comment: @doublep: Good point, voted to close.

Answer (score 4):

**Python**: 173 characters

```
for i in range(5):
    a=""
    for j in str(z):
        y=int("03330222220201002020330220102001030022220303003020"[int(j)*5+i])*8
        a+="."+("#"*9+"."*14+"##"+"."*6+"#")[y:y+8]
    print a
```

Comment: please note you need to count new lines as well. it's 168 chars with identation but w/o new lines. Need to add +5 for \n = 173

Comment: I don't have Python installed on this machine so I'll take your word for it that this works, somehow. There is a voice in the back of my head telling me that you can somehow reduce your character count using a list comprehension, but of course, I may be totally wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Bash:  9 characters

```
figlet $z
```

;)

Comment: ewwww... this is not solution in bash but in figlet.pls no trivialisms!

Comment: @EnTrr - When I got here the question was at -1 with a vote to close, I figured it was going to be closed soon and I shouldn't take it so seriously... ;)

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby - 139 chars

```
(0..4).map{|i|puts z.to_s.chars.map{|j|(?#*9+?.*14+'##'+?.*6+?#)[(?0+"ubp9x453o9jzme0cs08".to_i(36).to_s(4))[j.to_i*5+i].to_i*8,8]+' '}*''}
```

Output for `z = 365`

```
> asciinum.rb
######## ######## ########
.......# #....... #.......
######## ######## ########
.......# #......# .......#
######## ######## ########
```