# How to implement Remote Desktop for Android?

Tags: remote-access, rdp

I want to develop a Remote Desktop application for Android , Part of my project, Can please someone help me out? or have tried any thing?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can take a look at some open-source solutions and gain some inspiration. After some quick search on google I found this project http://jrdesktop.sourceforge.net/ which is an open source java implementation of a remote dsktop app. I also found a SO discussion on the topic: [Implementing my own remote desktop in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080361/implementing-my-own-remote-desktop-in-java)

Good luck! :)