# How to encode a bit string into a UTF16 string in JavaScript as to not waste any space?

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm, binary

Say you have a byte string: `"0100010101110001010..."`. How to convert it into a UTF16 string (eg: "A|b☮"), and how to convert it back to the original byte string?

I have attempted the implementation below, but it seems like my understanding in UTF16 is not good enough and the code breaks in some (I don't know which) cases.

```
var pad = function(x){
    while(x.length%16!==0)
        x="0"+x;
    return x;
}
var unpack_bin = function(a){
    for(var r="",i=0,l=a.length;i<l;++i)
        r+=pad((a[i].charCodeAt(0)-36).toString(2));
    return r.slice(r.indexOf("1")+1);
}
var pack_bin = function(a) {
    for (var s="",i=0,l=a.length,a=pad("1"+a);i<l;i+=16) 
        s+=String.fromCharCode(parseInt(a.slice(i,i+16),2)+36);
    return s;
}
```

Comment: i don't think you can; certain unicode "charcodes" don't like sitting next to eachother, so what comes out might differ from what goes in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't fit 16 bits into one UTF-16 unit, but you can fit 14 bits.

[CJK Unified Ideographs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs) is a continuous block of 20941 valid unicode characters, each encoded by a single UTF-16 unit.

```
function pad(x, div){
    while(x.length%div!==0)
        x="0"+x;
    return x;
}

function unpack_bin(packedString){
    var binString = "";
    for(var i=0; i<packedString.length; ++i) {
        var binValue = packedString[i].charCodeAt(0)-0x4E00;
        binString += pad(binValue.toString(2), 14);
    }
    return binString.slice(binString.indexOf("1")+1);
}

function pack_bin(binString) {
    binString = pad("1"+binString, 14);
    var packedString = "";
    for(var i=0; i<binString.length; i+=14) {
        var charCode = parseInt(binString.slice(i, i+14), 2)+0x4E00;
        packedString += String.fromCharCode(charCode);
    }
    return packedString;
}
```

See also: [Twitter image encoding challenge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891643/twitter-image-encoding-challenge)

Comment: That sounds great but this isn't valid JavaScript. Did you just sketch that? I guess [this](http://lpaste.net/100178) is what you meant. It would be really cool if you fixed it and included a method for unpacking.

Comment: Oh, nevermind, I just understood what you've done. Here is a working code for someone needing it: http://lpaste.net/100183

Comment: @Viclib You're right, the code wasn't valid; I should have tested it before posting. I fixed the answer.